# Missing processing toolbox in QGIS 3.10

Tags: qgis, gdal, qgis-3, qgis-processing, osgeo4w

I no longer see the plugins, the processing toolbox and all the scripts in QGIS 3.10 LTR. They're not even in the "Processing" Menu. I tried looking to activate it from the menu bar but it's not the only problem, QGIS all in all is not connecting to the scripts.

I think I know that the problem is with python, I just need some help reversing it.

This is what I did:

1. I was experimenting with GDAL in th OSGeo4W shell
2. I needed to execute gdal_calc so following the tutorial I needed to set the path to the python app by exectuting the following code: `py3_env`
3. I executed `py3_env` many times after so it resulted in concatinating the paths as follows
   [image]
4. When I launched QGIS 3.10 this is what I have
   [image]

The not even a "Processing" Menu.

I imagine this requires that I reassign the path to the scripts ?

How can I fix this as I don't want to reinstall QGIS again.

Comment: Check if some of these answers could solve your problem https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=processing+toolbox

Comment: calling py3_env does not harm QGIS, it is called when you start QGIS, too.

Comment: Processing is a plugin that must be activated - perhaps it got turned off somehow? I also get it missing sometimes when running QGIS 3.10 as an App-V package, and have to go to the plugin manager and turn it off and on.